# How to make a Unity3D game just using C#

Tags: c#, graphics, unity-game-engine

And is that possible for Unity3D to do the same thing like Opengl to draw the vertices on the screen?
What I want to do is to migrate a XNA project to Unity environment in order to make it cross different platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using Meshes will do the work for you :)
You can render meshes consisted of vertices & normals & uvs & indices.

[Click here for the documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html)

Comment: Thank you for answering. I suppose it should be able to work

Answer (score 0):

If you must have custom rendering there are [GL](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL.html) and [Graphics](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Graphics.html) classes you can use. Render to texture is possible too. In Unity, code is usually written in class that inherits MonoBehaviour and it has Start, Update (once per frame), FixedUpdate (physics) and other callbacks for you to use.

Comment: Is there any specific tools or library that I can use to do this task?